using listAll() on firebase storagereference is always going to onFailure
I am trying to get the names and url of the subfolders and files inside a directory in Firebase Storage.
But the listAll is always going to onFailure
I tried the following code:
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference listRef = storage.getReference();
            listRef = listRef.child("Musics");
            Log.d("hafiz", listRef.getName());

        listRef.listAll()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                        for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                            // All the prefixes under listRef.
                            // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
                            Log.d("hafiz", prefix.getName());
                        }

                        for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                            // All the items under listRef.
                            Log.d("hafizitem", item.getName());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
//
                        Log.d("jibon", e.getMessage());
                    }
                });


i am getting this error:

An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.

here is my storage rule:
    service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
         allow read, write;
    }
  }
}


Try logging the entire Exception, not just the message contained in it.  Log.e("jibon", "listAll error", e)

Thanks, I had to append rule 2, that was the error

If you resolved the problem, then please answer your own question with the specific steps you took.  This will help others in the future with the same problem.

prepend rules_version = '2' to the rule. For example, here
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
         allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56169820/24905876
